# How to display multiple cells in Table Search

Tags: javascript, html, search, html-table

I'm wondering if there is a way for this search bar that I'm using to display multiple elements. As it is right now if I search for "123" in a pool with "321" "1234" "123" "12345" The only displayed value would be the first one: "1234". I'd like for all values that match my search to be displayed, therefore this would be the correct search result: "1234" "123" "12345".

Any answer is appreciated.

Here's the current code that I have:

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
if (search.value.length > 0 && search.value != '') {
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
        if       (cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
            cells.forEach(function(element) {
                element.style.display = "none";
            });
            cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
            break;
        } else {
            cells.forEach(function(element) {
                if (cells[i] !== element) {
                    element.style.display = "table-cell";
                }
            });
        }
    }
} else {
    cells.forEach(function(element) {
        if (cells[i] !== element) {
            element.style.display = "table-cell";
        }
    });

}
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>321</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>abcde</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cells` selector returns a `nodelist` this is an arrayish object. That doesn't have the `forEach` function.

However we can borrow from the Array object:

`Array.prototype.forEach`

What I did to solve the other problem is create an `indexArray` as a lookup array. that keeps track of the indices that contained the search string. Then when we loop all the cells we can turn the ones of that don't show up in the lookup array

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var indexArray = []; //look up array
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
      //restore the cells:
      cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    
      //if search value is found the value will be 0 if it starts a the beginning
      if (cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
        indexArray.push(i); //push index into lookup
      }
    }
    //loop over all cells
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(element, index) {
      if (indexArray.indexOf(index) === -1) //if index is not present in look up, set display to none
        element.style.display = "none";
    });

});
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>321</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>abcde</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great and will use it, but would it be possible to make it so the search works in a way that if I type "1" it would show only the results that start with 1, not the ones containing a 1?

Comment: Just changed the -1 to a 0, this will do just that!

Comment: This is working great so far for my project, but one last thing. If you search for "abcde" the result shows up, no problem, but when you backspace all the way back to "abc" it still only shows "abcde". Would it be possible to fix this with the current code that I have?

Answer (score 0):

below code is enough if you want to show which cell has contain that search; also you can test on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bzcdomjs/

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");
search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
    cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    if (search.value.length > 0 && search.value != '') {
            if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        cells[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
});
```